# Distribution of sum of two exponential random variables

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory

Suppose $X \sim exp(\lambda)$ and $Y \sim exp(\lambda)$. I want to find the c.d.f. of $X + Y$.

I know I need to do a convolution so I set this up:

$$P(X + Y \leq z) = \int_{0}^{z} F_{X}(z - x_2)f_{Y}(x_2)$$

I'm not sure if this is correct - I'm guessing. I know the c.d.f of exponential $\lambda$ is $1 - e^{-\lambda x}$ and I know the p.d.f is $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$, but I still can't solve the integral.

Can someone please help me with this?

EDIT:

With mostafa's help:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda y} - e^{-\lambda(z - y) - \lambda y} \mathop{dy} = \int_{0}^{z} e^{-\lambda y} - e^{-\lambda z} \mathop{dy} = \frac{e^{-\lambda z}(-\lambda z + e^{\lambda z} - 1)}{\lambda}$$

but I think this diverges?

Comment: To see whether the first formula (assuming it has $dx_2$ and that $X$ and $Y$ are independent) is correct or not, write $\mathbb P(X + Y < z) = \iint_{x + y < z} f_X(x) f_Y(y) \, dx dy$. Can you get it into the form on the rhs? You lost the factor of $\lambda$ in the last formula. If you decide to change the upper limit from $z$ to $\infty$, you need to take an expression for $F_X(z - y)$ which is valid for $y > z$. $\, 1 - e^{-\lambda (z - y)}$ isn't, which is why you're getting a divergent integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

First of all, we have $z\ge 0$. Therefore $$\Pr\{X+Y\le z\}{=\Pr\{X<z-Y\}\\=\int_0^\infty \Pr\{X<z-y\}f(y)dy\\=\int_0^z (1-e^{-\lambda (z-y)})e^{-\lambda y}dy}$$the last equality holds since $$\Pr\{Y>Z\}=0$$

Comment: Can you please see my edit? Thanks

Comment: Since $\Pr\{Y>Z\}=0$ the integral reduces to $\int _0^z e^{-\lambda y}-e^{-\lambda z}dy$

Comment: Does the final answer look right? I used a calculator

Comment: @astronomer6353, yes. It is correct...

Comment: $f_Y(y) \neq e^{-\lambda y}$. And taken literally as written, the last integral in your answer diverges.

Comment: I have clarified it before in the comments, but added it now to my answer for self-containment. Thanks for mentioning.